# Need assistance with PIVOT table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that I need to convert into a PIVOT table. Right now the data appears as such...

[image]

But I really want it to appear with the ProcessDesc as COLUMN HEADINGS and the "intersection" being DateCompleted, such as....

[image]

How can I do this exactly? The query that creates the original query is as follows...

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.DisplayName, EPM.DateCompleted, PS.SortNumber, PS.ProcessDesc
FROM dbo.EPM
  INNER JOIN dbo.PS
    ON EPM.EPS = PS.ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.E
    ON EPM.ID = E.ID
WHERE DisplayName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY E.DisplayName, PS.SortNumber
```

Comment: Do you want just 4 columns or all columns?

Comment: I do not need ProcessSort, just the other 3. ProcessSort was just being used to sort the ProcessDesc fields, which will be the main column headings. @Mihai

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

`#TEMP` here will be the one generated by your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.DisplayName, EPM.DateCompleted, PS.SortNumber, PS.ProcessDesc
FROM dbo.EPM
  INNER JOIN dbo.PS
    ON EPM.EPS = PS.ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.E
    ON EPM.ID = E.ID
WHERE DisplayName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY E.DisplayName, PS.SortNumber
```

## SOLUTION USING DYNAMIC SQL

```
declare @sql1 as varchar(4000) = ''
declare @sql2 as varchar(4000) = ''
declare @sql3 as varchar(4000) = ''

set @sql1 = 
'select
    DisplayName
'

select @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   ,max(case when ProcessDesc = ''' + ProcessDesc + ''' then DateCompleted end) as [' + ProcessDesc +']
'
from #TEMP
order by ProcessDesc, ProcessSort

set @sql3 =
'
from #TEMP
group by DisplayName
ORDER BY DisplayName
'
print @sql1 + @sql2 +@sql3
exec(@sql1 + @sql2 +@sql3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.DisplayName, 
MAX(CASE WHEN PS.ProcessDesc='Set-Up Form 1' THEN EPM.DateCompleted END) as [Set-Up Form 1],
MAX(CASE WHEN PS.ProcessDesc='Set-Up Form 2' THEN EPM.DateCompleted END) as [Set-Up Form 2],
MAX(CASE WHEN PS.ProcessDesc='Set-Up Form 3' THEN EPM.DateCompleted END) as [Set-Up Form 3] 
FROM dbo.EPM
  INNER JOIN dbo.PS
    ON EPM.EPS = PS.ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.E
    ON EPM.ID = E.ID
WHERE DisplayName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY E.DisplayName
ORDER BY E.DisplayName, PS.SortNumber
```

Comment: Thanks. The thing is, the columns will really need to be dynamic. The ProcessDesc field, which will be the main column headings, could change. Can you adapt your code? Thanks again! @Mihai

Comment: @WebDevGuy So you want a column for each ProcessDesc value?

Comment: @WebDevGuy You cant have it dynamic and only partial,you either get all values or you choose.If they change how do I know how to get them?You can`t.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Mihai . I need to have a column for EVERY ProcessDesc value. (Not partial.) Even if all the dates are null I need these too. All data. By the way, I'm amazed at what you came up with so far, in just a few lines. Thanks! :)

Comment: @WebDevGuy I`ll look into it tomorrow,if nobody answers.